# Java Web Start Authentication Option

Tags: authentication, java-web-start

Ok, before you think that this is a simplistic request and that it must be out there; I've done about 2-3 hours of searching with no results.  Is there a way to pass authentication information through Java Web Start (javaws) to access a password protected website?

Essentially what I'm working towards is an auto-restart of a javaws application without having to re-implement what javaws does to pull the jar's down and then having to run Java on the downloaded application.  I've really been trying to find information on this but no one wants to do the same thing I'm doing (mainly because if you have authentication then you would want someone to authenticate).

The authentication method is basic and I've tried embedding the username/password into the URL to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[aol]Me too.  I found this thread as part of my search for the same.[/aol]

The closest that I have found is [this wiki-page for a JNLP started trading application](http://www.dukascopy.com/wiki/index.php?title=Auto_launching).  Excerpt:

```
javaws -J-Djnlp.client.username=YOUR_LOGIN -J-Djnlp.client.password=YOUR_PASSWORD JNLPURL
```

I still receive a Java-generated error for the application that I'm attempting to use (ATEN KVM-over-IP on Supermicro motherboard), but I see some session-specific junk in the JNLP that changes with each request.

Comment: For new readers: Do not get your hopes high.  It does not seem to work in general.

Answer (score 0):

Is this [discussion](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CB8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.sun.com%2Fthread.jspa%3FthreadID%3D5296343&ei=4IZtTK--AoSUnQfduNymCA&usg=AFQjCNHZodKLRuC9tlUujywu1c9ND6goAg) useful?