# How to keep java webstart from asking for a password (after restart)?

Tags: java, java-web-start

Java webstart keeps asking for a password. It is important to note that we exhibit this problem only after restarting the computer.

In otherwords, if we select "remember password", java remembers the password. However, after a restart of the computer, it seems java forgets the password, and I need to reauthenticate when launching the application.

This does not happen if i merely close/reopen the browser. Only on a full restart of the computer.

Does anyone else exhibit this problem? Even better, does anyone know what is causing this, or how to fix it?

Our code is compiled with java 1.7.0.51. My client is some flavor of java 8.

I've seen discussions on stack exchange here:

[Java Web Start keeps asking to authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996439/java-web-start-keeps-asking-to-authenticate)

And here:

[Java Web Start Authentication Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284668/java-web-start-authentication-option)

Other google top results are irrelevant.

Comment: Please be more specific about what kind of authentication you are talking, normally a java application (or applet) will not need authentication unless explicitly programmed that way. How is your authentication stored so that the next new startet application (or applet) can access it at all?

Comment: We are using Basic Authentication.

So, I'm talking about the following: we download our application, webstart.jnlp. After this, we are prompted by Java for authentication merely to download the jar files. We haven't even reached our application yet. So it is my understanding, that Java handles the storage of the credentials.

After the jars are downloaded, we prompt again for for a username and password for application access. But we want this to happen every time.

Comment: Hmm, good luck I'd say, interesting question.

Comment: Is this expected behavior on Java's end? This seems like a bug.